# Redireccionar una ruta por un onclick en VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio, .net

Cordial Saludo,

Estoy trabajando con VB.NET y tengo un enlace `a` en el code behind que me lleva a otro sitio, necesito que el enlace se pase por un `onclick` dentro del `a` pero no logro escapar las comillas correctamente y no me ejecuta la redirección del enlace.

Cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

COD ORIGINAL VB.NET:

```html
Opciones_Trabajador.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<li><a target=_blank  href='" & sOpciones.Rows(j).Item(1).ToString & "'>" & sOpciones.Rows(j).Item(0).ToString & "</a></li>"))
```

MI INTENTO:

```html
Opciones_Trabajador.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<li><a target=_blank  onclick='location.href = href='" & sOpciones.Rows(j).Item(1).ToString & "'>" & sOpciones.Rows(j).Item(0).ToString & "'</a></li>"))
```

Pero no me funciona cuando agrego en `onclick = "location.href = """`

Comment: buen día, en tu intento estás poniendo esto `onclick='location.href = href=`, debería ser `onclick="location.href = ' ' "`

Comment: Buen día, si cai en cuenta pero la paso como mencionas y de igual forma no me lleva al enlace

Comment: Y para qué necesitas mandarlo con un onclick? si con el `href=" "` bastaría.

Comment: No se puede ver el enlace de redirección cuando se pasa el mouse por el encima, en la parte de abajo muestra la ruta, la cual debo ocultar, al pasarle el enlace por un onclick con JS no se muestra eso necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución con el siguiente código.

lo que buscaba era que el hipervinculo de la etiqueta `<a href="#"></a>` no se muestre en la parte de abajo `bottom - left.`

Con esto lo solucione.

Asigne un `Data` en la etiqueta y la recorri por un bucle `for`.

```js
<script>
    var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-href]');
        for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
              var aTag = aTags[i];
              aTag.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    var ele = e.target;
    window.location.replace(ele.getAttribute('data-href'));
              });
          }
</script>
```

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-per" datahref="../Extranet/home.aspx">
  <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>Dashboard
</a>
```